# SelectNodes return null

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, selectnodes

I am using `SelectNodes` to read xml nodes but i am getting null when i try `GetElementsByTagName` i get the values.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(DownloadFile);
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
xmlnode = xml.GetElementsByTagName("CruisePriceSummaryResponse");

for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
{
    XmlNodeList rooms = xml .SelectNodes("RoomSize/CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize");
    for(int j = 0; j < rooms.Count; j++)
    {
        string bestFare = rooms[j].SelectSingleNode("BestFare/TotalPrice").InnerText;
        string fullFare = rooms[j].SelectSingleNode("FullFare/TotalPrice").InnerText;

        // do whatever you need
    }
}
```

I want to read `TotalPrice` from `BestFare` and `FullFare` Each child has two innerchilds `BestFare` and `FullFareand` I need to read each `TotalPrice`.

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCruisePriceSummaryResponse
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OpenseasAPI.ServiceModel">

        <CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
            <AvailablePromos
                xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                <d3p1:string>FLA</d3p1:string>
                <d3p1:string>FLB</d3p1:string>
            </AvailablePromos>
            <Brand>PA</Brand>
            <CruiseCategory i:nil="true"/>
            <RoomSize>
                <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                    <BestFare>
                        <TotalPrice>2798.0000000</TotalPrice>
                    </BestFare>
                    <FullFare>
                        <TotalPrice>3198.000000</TotalPrice>
                    </FullFare>
                    <PaxCount>2</PaxCount>
                </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                    <BestFare>
                        <TotalPrice>2796.000000</TotalPrice>
                    </BestFare>
                    <FullFare>
                        <TotalPrice>4196.000000</TotalPrice>
                    </FullFare>
                    <PaxCount>4</PaxCount>
                </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
            </RoomSize>
            <ShipCode>PD</ShipCode>
        </CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
        <CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
            <AvailablePromos
                xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                <d3p1:string>FLA</d3p1:string>
                <d3p1:string>LF1</d3p1:string>
            </AvailablePromos>
            <Brand>PA</Brand>
            <RoomSize>
                <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                    <BestFare>
                        <TotalPrice>1298.000000</TotalPrice>
                    </BestFare>
                    <FullFare>
                        <TotalPrice>3498.000000</TotalPrice>
                    </FullFare>
                    <PaxCount>2</PaxCount>
                </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                    <BestFare>
                        <TotalPrice>1796.000000</TotalPrice>
                    </BestFare>
                    <FullFare>
                        <TotalPrice>5396.000000</TotalPrice>
                    </FullFare>
                    <PaxCount>4</PaxCount>
                </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
            </RoomSize>
            <ShipCode>PJ</ShipCode>
        </CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
    </ArrayOfCruisePriceSummaryResponse>
```

Help would be appreciated. I do not want to use linq as this is a SSIS project using VS2008 and it doesnot support linq.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never load or read the source XML. Your code

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
xmlnode = xml.GetElementsByTagName("CruisePriceSummaryResponse");
```

creates an empty XML document, and then tries to get elements from the empty xml.

You need to call `XmlDocument.Load` or `XmlDocument.LoadXML` to read the xml from a file or a string.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("pathtosomefile.xml");
XmlNodeList xmlnode = xml.GetElementsByTagName("CruisePriceSummaryResponse");
```

Comment: Thanks i forget to add this line in the question posted and i am able to see the values in xmlnode but selectnodes is the problem here which is retuning null. P.S i have updated my question and added the missing xml.load line.